# Print lint rule out with ALE in Vim

Tags: vim, eslint, flowtype, vim-plugin

At the moment I have the following in my `vimrc` to show the linter error message at the bottom of my screen:

```
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%linter% says: %s'
```

How do I customise this so that I get the name of the lint rule (rather than just the description).

Comment: You'll find the possible keywords [in the plugin help](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/blob/99e9417ef901824200040c6a2d3e84f2e0ff4b8e/doc/ale.txt#L933-L945). Anything beyond that would require an enhancement of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `%code%`. See `:help g:ale_echo_msg_format`. You can put just about any characters you want before or after `code`, and that part of the message will be removed if there's no error code. The default value for the option is `'%code: %%s'`.